# In the Users page, how are tags chosen?

Tags: support, tags, users-page

In the list of users by reputation, three tags are showing for each user:

> [image]

How are those tags selected? Those are not the top three tags, e.g. in my case:

> [image]

So how are the selected? Random?

Comment: In my case, the 3 I see from your profile are [tag:email], [tag:mobile-web], and [tag:comment-replies], and it seems they are the same every time I refresh the page...perhaps they are chosen based on the user logged in viewing the users?

Comment: @DarkCygnus that is because you see the weekly reputation gain. If you go to all time reputation pretty sure you will see same tags I mention here. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I assume your result is wrong in this query of mine: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268008/158100 ? It at least shouldn't take mandatory tags into account, by the looks of it.

Comment: @rene what result is wrong? I don't mean the weekly/monthly views which are affected by time, I mean the "all time reputation" view which should take into account the whole activity, so it should match what we see in the profile page.

Comment: My query mimics which tags you should see on the all time reputation league. It can help to determine what the actual order is if that query returns the same result.